# Is there any open-source object-oriented GIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, vector

Most GIS are layer based. But I am looking for open-source object-oriented GIS. Is there any out there?

By object-oriented I mean logical data model for vector GIS. Here's [explanation of my definitions](http://books.google.ru/books?id=0Yvg_PErYRkC&pg=PA39&dq=%22object+oriented%22+gis+open-source&hl=EN&sa=X&ei=HC1RT76ADrKQ4gTxzYznDQ&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22object%20oriented%22%20gis%20open-source&f=true).

Comment: Interesting question, I like very much this idea of object oriented representation because that is much more natural way of representing things than the layer-based system and that makes programming a lot easier.

Answer (score 10):

[Neo4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) is a graph-based database (where nodes are akin to objects) and [Neo4j Spatial](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial) is a "library of utilities for Neo4j that faciliates the enabling of spatial operations on data". Some slides [here](http://www.slideshare.net/peterneubauer/2011-07oscon) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/craigtaverner/neo4j-spatial-backing-a-gis-with-a-true-graph-database).

Also see this related question on StackOverflow: [NoSQL and spatial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041622/nosql-and-spatial-data)

Other examples of object-oriented spatial databases are listed in this Wikipedia article: [Object-based spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_spatial_database)

Answer (score 2):

I know very little about the theory but I think you can get a pseudo object-oriented solution with Postgis and an ORM like Django framework or SqlAlchemy.

I use a combination of Postgis and Django and the way of dealing with the geographic models is object oriented, but they are stored as a relational database.

For example, you can have a 'point' model and a 'data' (key:value) model.
Any 'point' instance has an add_data() method and also geographic methods like is_near(), contains(), get_xy(), etc.

Than you can have a 'BurgerShop(point)' and BusStop(point) class with special methods like BurgerShop.get_burger_types(), BurgerShop.get_nearest_busstop() or BusStop.get_nearest_burgershop().